# SSRS SQL-Restart subscription runs all scheduled Reports

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I am using the folling SQL-Script to restart faild SSRS mailing subscriptions:

```
DECLARE @ScheduledReportName varchar(200)
DECLARE @JobID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @LastRunTime datetime
Declare @JobStatus Varchar(100)
--------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @RunAllReport CURSOR
SET @RunAllReport = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT 
CAT.[Name] AS RptName
, res.ScheduleID AS JobID
, sub.LastRuntime
, CASE WHEN job.[enabled] = 1 THEN 'Enabled'
ELSE 'Disabled'
END AS JobStatus

FROM
dbo.Catalog AS cat
INNER JOIN dbo.Subscriptions AS sub
ON CAT.ItemID = sub.Report_OID
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule AS res
ON CAT.ItemID = res.ReportID
AND sub.SubscriptionID = res.SubscriptionID
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS job
ON CAST(res.ScheduleID AS VARCHAR(36)) = job.[name]
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules AS sch
ON job.job_id = sch.job_id
INNER JOIN dbo.Users U
ON U.UserID = sub.OwnerID

----------------Filter der Subscriptions----------------

where sub.subscriptionid in
(
SELECT subscriptionid
FROM Subscriptions AS S
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Catalog] AS C
ON C.ItemID = S.Report_OID
WHERE S.LastStatus like 'Failure sending mail%'
)

----------------Filter der Subscriptions----------------

ORDER BY U.UserName, RptName 
OPEN @RunAllReport
FETCH NEXT FROM @RunAllReport
INTO @ScheduledReportName,@JobID,@LastRunTime,@JobStatus
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Print @ScheduledReportName --&' ' & @JobID
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name =@JobID
FETCH NEXT FROM @RunAllReport
INTO @ScheduledReportName,@JobID,@LastRunTime,@JobStatus
END
CLOSE @RunAllReport
DEALLOCATE @RunAllReport
```

I run this if an subscripton fails. In my example I send the same Report to multiple persons as a subscription with differen parameters. Sometime one subscription fails and I want to restart the job. The query in the upper script provides the specific subscriptionID of the failed one.

But even though the ScheduleID is handed over AS JobID all the Reports are beeing resend to all people.
Is there something wrong with the script?

Pleas help me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the procedure in my old query:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name =@JobID
```

Runs all the Subscriptions under a ScheduleID AS JobID. So all Report with a SharedSchedule are launched again, by a job restart.

To restart only a specific supbscription I have to run the following command at its place, with the subscriptionID instead of the scheduleID:

```
exec [dbo].[AddEvent] 'TimedSubscription', @SubscriptionID;
```

This will add an event into the [dbo].[Event] table that will run the subscription passed in the parameter. So only the required Report will be sent.